# Backbone event fired too many times

Tags: model-view-controller, backbone.js, backbone-events

I'm trying to learn how to work with backbone. I'm currently trying to add sortable from jQuery ui to the todo application created by : Addy Osmani.

So I tried to trigger an event on the sortable drop event as I saw in a js fiddle. This event would trigger a function (`drop()`) in my item view, that triggers a function (`update-order()`) in my app view. I want this last function to re-order the todo list by `changeand` saving the new order.

The problem I have is that my function `updateOrder` is fired like 4 times, when the drop function is fired only one time, also the changing of order is not recorded, and I can't figure why.

Here is my example : http://www.fgtechs.fr/backbone/ I'm basically trying to invert the order on the drop event of the sortable.

I would have liked my function `updateOrder` to be triggered only once and the changes of order recorded ... but none of this happened ...

I really need your help.

Here is a part of my code (you can see the rest in my example):

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#widget-list').sortable({
                stop: function(event, ui) {
                    event.stopPropagation()
                    event.preventDefault();
                    ui.item.trigger('drop', ui.item.index());
                }
            });
        });    
    </script>


//on the drop, we invert the order
        updateOrder:function(event, model, position){
            alert('update-order');
            console.log(app.Widgets.length);
            app.Widgets.each(function (widget, order) {
                widget.save({
                    'order': app.Widgets.length-order
                });
            });
        }


//On the event drop, we trigger the function update order
drop: function(event, position) {
    this.$el.trigger('update-order', [this.model, position]);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i figured it out, the problem i had was that i triggered my update-order event on an attribute changing (order). Because that on one drop there is as much changing order than items, the event was triggered two many times, i simply change the way i triggered my update-order event and it worked perfectly.